# How to make an array with results from for loop and compare an index of array in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, max

I have the following problem (I am a beginner in python)

From a list of coordinates, I want those coordinates which have maximum distance. I thought of solving it as below:-

1- I have a list of coordinates C=[a,b,c,d]

2- I want to compute distance between each coordinate pair (d) ; this distance is calculated with a function of Molecular Dynamics library so I need to use it

3- Then I want to make an array with values as [[a ,b, d1], [a,c,d2]....]

4- Then I want to compare the distances and see which has the maximum distance among all pairs ie element max([:,2])

5- Finally I want an output of the coordinates which have the max distance

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Homework questions should include what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: To amplify @MooingRawr: please read [mcve].

Comment: One. Those are lists not arrays.

Two. Pythagoras' Theorem is useful...

Comment: You also need to be more precise with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach: first use `itertools.combinations` to make all possible two coordinate combinations of your coordinates.  Then sort them based on the distance between the coordinate pairs.  Take the last one in the sorted list as the maximally distant pair:

```
from itertools import combinations

coordinates = [(28, 15), (94, 58), (12, 34), (23, 56), (83, 55), (98, 17)]

def calculate_distance(coordinate_pair):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = coordinate_pair

    return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5

print(sorted(combinations(coordinates, 2), key=calculate_distance)[-1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
((12, 34), (98, 17))
```